# Inline php with forms

Tags: php, inline

```
<?php
echo '<form action="';
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
echo '" method="post"><input class="loginDropdownInput" type="text" name="user" value=';
if(isset($_COOKIE['rememeredusername'])=='true'){
  echo $_COOKIE['rememeredusername'];
} else {
  echo 'Username';
}
echo 'onclick="if(this.value == "Username") this.value="";" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value="" Username""; /></br></br><input class="loginDropdownInput" type="password" name="pass" value="Password" onclick="if(this.value == "Password"") this.value="";"  onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value="Password";"/>
?>

<span>
  </br>
  </br>
  <span class="rememberMe">Remember me</span>
  <input class="rememberMeBox" value="rememberme" name="rememberme" type="checkbox"/>
</span>

<a class="forgotPassword" href="../Accounts/forgot.php">Forgot your password?</a>

<?php
echo '<p class="loginErrorMessage">';
if ($userexists=='false'){
  echo "Uh oh, try again...";
}  
echo'</p><input class="submitDropdownInput" type="image" src="../Images/submitDropdownInput.png" alt="Login"/></form>';
?>
```

This is my code for a login portion of my site. However, input.loginDropdownInput keeps coming out with a value of "Usernameonclick="if(this.value" instead of "Username". 
Where is my syntax error?

Comment: This is completely invalid gibberish! O_o Mostly a copy and paste issue I suppose, so please fix it.

Comment: you need to know how it works php [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)

Comment: ^^ sorry its kinda hard to fix it this text editor is blah.

Comment: Is that first `<form...>` a string in PHP or is that HTML with PHP inside it? That's the biggest part that needs fixing here. If the former, give us the complete surrounding PHP code, if the latter, the code is nonsense.

Comment: I think the latter.... its an input value with php inside it ALL inside php lol.

Comment: Then give us more code if there is more.

Comment: okay i will add more of the code.

Comment: I see no inline PHP in this code. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly are your needs, but I would seriously recommend you to stop mixing so much PHP and markup like you're doing right now, it's horrible to read and almost impossible to maintain.

Try doing something like:

PHP part:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['rememeredusername'])){ 
  $form['username'] = $_COOKIE['rememeredusername'];
} else {
  $form['username'] = "Username";
}
$form['username'] = htmlspecialchars($form['username']);
```

HTML part:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input class="loginDropdownInput" type="text" name="user" value="<?=$form['username']?>"
  onfocus="if(this.value == 'Username') this.value='';"  
  onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value='Username';" />
```

Also you were using the onclick event, when you actually want it to be onfocus.

That's what I could understand from your code, try to make your php reproduce something like this if this is what you need.

-- Fixed some code errors.

Comment: I would seriously recommend you to stop mixing so much PHP and markup like you're doing right now

Comment: And, please, write vertically, not horizontally. It's hard as hell to read a line of code of some megabytes long.